# Effective automatic refresh of UITableview without user interaction (IOS 5)

Tags: xcode, ios5, push-notification

I have never coded an App with Push Notifications and I have a very general question.
I would like to refresh a UITableview's data (coming from a webservice) automaticaly without "pull to refresh" or any other user's interaction. Is it possible to use Push notifications to inform my app for a data change, in order to avoid polling every xx seconds wasting bandwidth and battery?

In other words, while my app runs in the foreground (maybe) I can handle the message and the user wont receive a popup but what happens otherwise?

Is there any other way to achieve the same result?

I am going to use IOS 5.0+

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make a server HTTP-Request which only returns something if there was a change. Then in case this response is not empty you can reload the data. The function you can call by a NSTimer.

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(get) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

and

```
-(void)get {
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/app.php"]];
    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    if(![responseString isEqualToString:@""]) {
    // reload
    }
}
```

Comment: or combinate this with `didReceiveLocalNotification` (answer by Stephen Darlington above)

Comment: Thanks! This helps a lot. Unfortunately I cannot vote up since I have no 15 reputation points!

Comment: You said that you wanted to avoid polling! Just because there is no data in the body doesn't mean that the radio is switched off or that no data is transferred.

Answer (score 1):

When your app is running, you can register to receive push notifications. Then it's simply a matter of implementing the method, making it update your tableview.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif {
```

It's pretty well [documented by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW1).