# Xcode push notifications without alert

Tags: xcode, notifications, push, alert, mapkit

I have just implemented Push Notifications in my iPhone App.
And I am searching for almost a similar thing like here:

[Effective automatic refresh of UITableview without user interaction (IOS 5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10088298/effective-automatic-refresh-of-uitableview-without-user-interaction-ios-5)

Let me say I have two Users. one user is changing his position. With MKMapKit I can determine when this happens and I send a location change to my server. Then I send a Push Notification to the other device and he sees "live" that the user is changing his position. But there is one problem: if the device is locked I'll get a Notification every few seconds if the other device is moving. Is there a possibility to hide the alerts and that only the app knows that the other user has changed his position? So I am searching for a possibility that my app knows to update the location of the other users if he changed but without getting every time an alert. And a NSTimer is not the thing I am searching for because this is not a very effective way I think.

Thank you in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure if your App is locked, i.e. in the background you can't directly send messages to it.
Have you're own Server track user movement and ask it about the latest movement-history from inside your App the next time it becomes active?

Comment: Yes I have this with an update button. But now I try to do it automatically that there is no need for an update button.

Comment: Yes, build a server and have it track user movement from other apps. Then update automatically with data from your server.

Comment: Yes but how to let the App automatically know from the Server that other user have moved?